# Unexpected token u with node-red

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am facing an error while parsing my string to json, I have a string that looks like this

```
{"rxpk":[{"tmst":13885860,"time":"2016-04-13T12:52:17.085935Z","chan":1,"rfch":1,"freq":868.300000,"stat":1,"modu":"LORA","datr":"SF12BW125","codr":"4/5","lsnr":6.0,"rssi":-45,"size":15,"data":"QAMBAQKAPgIFXA2ikKV7"}]}
```

I am using node-red to create a flow diagram to parse it, I have a function block which makes the following

```
obj = JSON.parse(msg.payload); 
var data = obj.rxpk[0].data;
return data
```

However, I get the Unexpected token u. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Regards!

EDIT: adding pic, I have something as show in the picture, I have replaced my function that was doing the `JSON.parse` by the block json.format, thus unexpected token is gone, but still I cannot retrieve my data field from the json string[image]

Comment: `Unexpected token u` pretty much always means you're trying to do `JSON.parse(undefined)`. Based on the information you've provided, I can't say why `msg.payload` is `undefined` but that's likely the problem.

Comment: well `msg.payload` should be the string that I have set, how can I check it?

Comment: `console.log(msg.payload)`? If you want help fixing the problem, you'll need to share code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I don't know node-RED at all, but the problem appears to be that the JSON-processing node runs before the UDP gets any data (since it is asynchronous). You need to wait to do the next step until the UDP listener has received data. I don't know how to do that, but here's a UDP flow that you could study, maybe: http://flows.nodered.org/flow/e7d29861b7717186921f

Comment: I faced the same problem earlier when sending json string from MQTT LENS to my mqtt node. By copy/pasting json string from website to MQTTLENS I used to get 'Unexpected token'. I resolved this issue by sending manually written json string